# Mysql-Insert Long BLOB

Tags: java, mysql

In my server max_allowed_packet value is 16mb, I cann't change the server configuration.
I want to insert a file around 25mb. How can I Insert a file into mysql blob?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the file in chunks of 16 Mb (and inserting them part by part) would be your best bet if you really can't up the `max_allowed_packet_value`.

Comment: Yes, we can do this. Anyother solution to store entire file into a single row-blob? is this possible?- Thanks.Balakrishnan

Answer (score 0):

Divide the file into parts and try save it into two columns.

Comment: Yes, we can do this. Anyother solution to store entire file into a single row-blob? - Thanks.Balakrishnan